# Use of definite article before "customer service"

Tags: definite-article

I was recently asked by a non native English speaker why "the" isn't necessary before "customer service" in the sentence "You should call customer service if there's a problem". Is it because "customer service" is short for "the customer service department"? Are there other examples where we don't need to include "the" before the object when using verbs such as "contact", "call", etc?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. When talking about parts of an organization, it is normal to shorten

> the xyz department

to

> xyz

Here are some examples:

> Accounts has prepared the budgets for the next financial year.
> You need to talk to production about that
> Simon in human resources may be able to help you

Comment: I once dated Sharon from Accounts. She was very particular about the capital A.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I guess she wasn't a fan of e e cummings then...

Comment: No, and she (and I) would write 'Mike, Accounts have prepared the budgets for the next financial year, and Building Services are coming to fix the aircon' (even if it was one person)'. Us whacky Brits, eh?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, "customer service" isn't referring to a specific department within a company, but rather the general concept of a service provided to customers. We don't need "the" when talking about general ideas or concepts.

The case is the same as in:
If you have any questions about benefits, you can contact **human resources**.

However, there are situations where "the" becomes necessary:

If you're referring to a specific department or person: "I spoke with the manager of customer service."
For emphasis: "**The customer service** at that company is excellent!"